# Is there a custom control similar to NSLevelIndicator with reverse coloring?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nscontrol, nslevelindicator

I need a control similar to `NSLevelIndicator` in `NSContinuousCapacityLevelIndicatorStyle`, but with reverse coloring. With `NSLevelIndicator`, the colors are like this:
Green up to the warning level, yellow from warning to critical level, red from critical level onwards. This is fine for, say, a volume control. But I have a value that corresponds to the filling of a gas tank: I want green for a full tank, yellow for warning and red for empty.
I have not found any means to change the colors of `NSLevelIndicator`.

So, before I start to write my own custom control, is there a `NSControl` available somewhere that already does what I want (of course I googled before asking, but to no avail)?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSLevelIndicator` (at least nowadays) does this automatically for you if you set a warning level higher than the critical level!

Comment: That's it! Thanks, I never came up with that idea.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass `NSLevelIndicator` and write your own `- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)theRect`

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>


@interface PBLevelIndicator : NSLevelIndicator {

    unsigned int mPercent;
}


@end  

#import "PBLevelIndicator.h"


@implementation PBLevelIndicator
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)theRect
{
    NSRect fillingRect = theRect;
    fillingRect.size.width = theRect.size.width*mPercent/100;   
    NSColor *indicatorColor;

    if( mPercent >= 99 )
    {
        indicatorColor = [NSColor greenColor];
    }
    else if (mPercent >50) 
    {
        indicatorColor = [NSColor yellowColor];
    }
    else
    {
        indicatorColor = [NSColor redColor];
    }
    [indicatorColor set];
    NSRectFill(fillingRect);
}

-(void) setPercentage:(unsigned int) inPercent
{
    mPercent = inPercent;
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
@end
```

Comment: That is a good idea, thank you. I tried it, but the new class is not key value coding-compliant. I will look deeper into this and see if I get it fixed.